# limited xcode profiles and bundle ids

Tags: ios, xcode, game-development

I want to ask apple to clear my profiles and bundle IDs but am not sure how to contact them about it.

I am currently developing my own mobile game in unity and exporting it using xcode.
when exporting my project Xcode game me this error:

Your maximum App ID limit has been reached. You may create up to 10 App IDs every 7 days.

project' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.DefaultCompany.My-project'.

Comment: Pay for the developer membership and the problem will go away or wait a few days.  You have exceeded the limit of the free tier.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.